# Fetching files from the folder and adding it into the JList

Tags: java, jlist, defaultlistmodel

This is my piece of code but i am not getting the output ...as it is not showing the file names in the JList...

```
    DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel();

    JList<String> list = new JList(model);
    try{
    File f = new File("pictures");
    String st[];
    st = f.list();
    for(int i=1;i<=st.length;i++)
    model.addElement(st[i]);

    }
    catch(Exception e){

    }
```

Comment: Well, stop catching exceptions and ignoring them. That way, you'll have a clear error message in the console indicating what and where the problem is. And read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: thanx dear... @JBNizet